# How to convert a PGresult to custom data type with libpq (PostgreSQL)

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

I'm using the libpq library in C to accessing my PostgreSQL database. So, when I do res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT point FROM test_point3d"); I don't know how to convert the PGresult I got to my custom data type.

I know I can use the PQgetValue function, but again I don't know how to convert the returning string to my custom data type.

Comment: What is your custom data type?

Comment: Something like this:
typedef struct Point3D
{
 char id[50];
 int idnull;
 double x;
 double y;
 double z; 
} Point3D;

I think that I must to parse the returning string of PQgetValue. I'm working on this so if it works I will post it here. :D

Comment: Almost everything is returned as string. Postgres' [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) are good example for something that's returned as string and has to be parsed by the application to be useful. Depending on what's "test_point3d.point" and how it's represented as/convert to string by Postgres, you'll have to parse that string and convert it to your data type.

Comment: Thanks for your replys.

Now I think that I understand what is the next to do. At the beggining  I was a bit lost.

So, it's the programmer's responsibility to parse the returned string.

That makes my question solved. :D

Greets to all.

Comment: you could add a simple `to_string` method for your data type to convert it to a string value for a parameter in an insert query, and likewise, a `from_string`

Answer (score 4):

The best way to think about this is that data types interact with applications over a textual interfaces.  Libpq returns a string from just about anything.  The programmer has a responsibility to parse the string and create a data type from it.  I know the author has probably abandoned the question but I am working on something similar and it is worth documenting a few important tricks here that are helpful in some cases.

Obviously if this is a C language type, with its own in and out representation, then you will have to parse the string the way you would normally.

However for arrays and tuples, the notation is basically

```
[open_type_identifier][csv_string][close_type_identifier]
```

For example a tuple may be represented as:

```
(35,65,1111111,f,f,2011-10-06,"2011-10-07 13:11:24.324195",186,chris,f,,,,f)
```

This makes it easy to parse.  You can generally use existing csv processers once you trip off the first and last character.  Moreover, consider:

```
select row('test', 'testing, inc', array['test', 'testing, inc']);
                       row                       
-------------------------------------------------
 (test,"testing, inc","{test,""testing, inc""}")
(1 row)
```

As this shows you have standard CSV escaping inside nested attributes, so you can, in fact, determine that the third attribute is an array, and then (having undoubled the quotes), parse it as an array.  In this way nested data structures can be processed in a manner roughly similar to what you might expect with a format like JSON.  The trick though is that it is nested CSV.

Comment: the `(` and `)` are used in custom data types as well, but not for native types